# How would I search a directoy for a filename not it's contents in PHP?

Tags: php, search

Alright I have several hundred different files in multiple directory under one main directory called Files. How would I create a PHP file inside the root directory (FIles) ands earch all sub-directories etc and then print the results to the user? However, I only want this search engine to search the filename and not it's contents. If possible could you provide a script already made or sample code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you say "search the filename" do you want to list files having that filename anywhere within the Files directory and sub-directories?  Will partial filename matching be needed (e.g. `img` to match `a_img1.gif`, etc.) or just the exact name? Do you want to stop at the first match, or list all matches?

Comment: If this question no longer requires additional answers, please mark the appropriate post as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

To search for files in PHP, you can use `glob`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

To get a file listing for a path, you can use `scandir`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

**Example**

```
$dir = "/path/to/search/in/*.txt"; //search a path for only .txt files
foreach(glob($dir) as $file)  
{
    //print out the files that match
    echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($file) . "<br />";
}
```

**Custom Recursive Glob**

From: http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=16233

```
rglob($pattern, $flags = 0, $path = '')
{
    if (!$path && ($dir = dirname($pattern)) != '.')
    {
        if ($dir == '\\' || $dir == '/') $dir = '';
            return rglob(basename($pattern), $flags, $dir . '/');
    }
    $paths = glob($path . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_NOSORT);
    $files = glob($path . $pattern, $flags);
    foreach ($paths as $p) $files = array_merge($files, rglob($pattern, $flags, $p . '/'));
    return $files;
}
```

Comment: have a look at the comment section for some examples using this function

Comment: Could you provide some example code for one that would work best for me?

Comment: This won't search sub-directories, as asked in the question.

Comment: @salathe: True. I added a recursive version.

Answer (score 2):

PHP5:

```
$dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/path");
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
// could use CHILD_FIRST if you so wish

foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    echo $file, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
/***********************************************************************
 * @name  AnyWhereInFiles
 * @author Faisal Shaikh 
 * @abstract This project is to find out a part of string from anywhere in any folder
 * @version 1.0  
 * @package anywhereinfiles
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *************************************************************************/
session_start();
?>
<title>Any where In Files || AnyWhereInFiles.php</title>
<head>
    <style>
        h1{color:  #233E99;}
        td{ font-size:11px; font-family:arial;vertical-align:top;border:1px solid #fff;}
        a{font-size:11px; font-family:arial;}
        .me{font-size:11px; font-family:arial;color:#333;}
    </style>
</head>
<h1>AnyWhereInFiles.php</h1>
<form action="<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>" method="POST">  
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="search">String </label></td>
                <td><input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter your string" value="<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['searchString']) && $_SESSION['searchString'] != null)
    echo $_SESSION['searchString'];
?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="directory">Folder </label></td>
                <td><input id="directory" type="text" name="directory"  value="<?php
echo getcwd();
?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="case">Case Sensitive </label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="case" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="maxtime">Max Execution Time </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="maxtime" value="30"/></td>
                <td>Do not change the value if you do not have an idea about it.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Search the string" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>

<?php
function getDirContents($dir, &$results = array())
{

    if ($_POST['search'] == null)
        exit;

    ini_set('max_execution_time', $_POST['maxtime']);

    $_SESSION['searchString'] = $_POST['search'];

    echo "<script>var elm = document.getElementById('search');elm.value='$_POST[search]';</script>";

    if (!isset($_POST['case']))
        $string = strtolower($_POST['search']);
    else
        $string = $_POST['search'];
    $files = scandir($dir);

    foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
        $path = realpath($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
        if (!is_dir($path)) {
            $content = file_get_contents($path);
            if (!isset($_POST['case']))
                $content = strtolower(file_get_contents($path));
            if (strpos($content, $string) !== false) {
                echo $path . "<br>";
            }
            $results[] = $path;
        } else if ($value != "." && $value != "..") {
            getDirContents($path, $results);
            $results[] = $path;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
if (isset($_POST['directory']))
    getDirContents($_POST['directory']);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//@endof file anywhereinfiles.php
//@note if you have query, need, idea, help; feel free to contact f.shaikh1993@gmail.com
?>

<br/>
<br/>
<span  class="me">"AnyWhereInFiles" is a Open Source Project, developed by <a href="mailto:f.shaikh1993@gmail.com">Faisal Shaikh</a> . 
<br /> 
<a href="https://github.com/skfaisal93/AnyWhereInFiles">https://github.com/skfaisal93/AnyWhereInFiles</a>
</span>
```

Original project: https://github.com/skfaisal93/AnyWhereInFiles

Comment: Thanks! Can I enquire what License this is under, Faisal?

Comment: you can use it for free.